# Mouse input position is being printed as Unity coordinates, but the actual coordinates used seem incorrect

Tags: unity

This will be hard to explain, but I'll try to keep it short and simple:

I'm trying to set the position of a UI rectangle to the position of the mouse when clicked. When initialized, the position of the rectangle works fine (if, during Awake(), I initially set it so that x = 100 and y = 100 and then check the Rect Transform component during run time, Pos X and Pos Y are both set to 100 as intended). However, if I use the X and Y coordinates of Input.mousePosition, Pos X and Pos Y are given strange numbers that I have no clue where they're coming from.

I don't think they're pixel coordinates because the value for Pos X of the rectangle when my mouse clicks at the farthest left possible during run time is a value over 300 when it should be 0, and that value goes up as I progressively click rightwards.

Now here's the strange bit. When I try to use print() to print the mouse position x and y values that I use to set the rectangle's position, they're printed as intended (clicking the bottom left of the game area yields x = 0 and y = 0) yet the rectangle's position is far from close the values printed (rectangle's position is x = 337.5 and y = 192.5).

Can someone please explain why this happens, and how I can fix it? I suppose I can manually fix it by subtracting the new position values by 337.5 for x and 162.5, but it feels too brute-force-ish and there's bound to be consequences down the line.

Here is a screenshot to help clarify my issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xebh.png
[image: Mouse Input Issue]

Comment: if your rectangle is a child of any gameobject then try to set `position` instead of `localPosition`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localPosition` and `position` has no difference if your `GameObject` is not a child of any other `Gameobject`. But if your `GameObject` is a child of any other `GameObject` then `localPosition` represents the `position` with respect to its `parent`. For example, if your `parent` has position `10,10,10` and its child `localPosition` is `0,0,0` then your child object is actually at `10,10,10`(Globally). If you change your `GameObject's localPosition` to `10,0,0` then it will replace its position and add 10 units in X-axis of `parent`. Now the `localPosition` of child is `10,0,0` and `position` (aka Global Position) will become `20,10,10`.

In your case `rectangle` is a child and you are setting `localPosition` and giving it coordinates according to Global Position. That's the point.

I hope you got my point.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `localPosition`, the position will be relative to the GameObjects parent. You should use `position` instead, if you want to work with absolute coordinates.

Comment: It works! But why does it use absolute coordinates when I used localPosition in line 16?